# When to use class inheritance or relations?

Tags: python, inheritance, relation, derived-class, many-to-one

I'm having a trouble deciding which to use, derived classes or a many to one relation.

For example, I'd like to have a class of Breed with average data pertaining to the breed, and then I'd like to have the class Dog for individual dog data that can refer to Breed for the average data. From what I understand, I can do that with either class inheritance or a many to one relation. But I'm not quite sure that the nuances between the two that will make me prefer one over the other.

Comment: Wouldn't a dog be an *instance*, rather than *subclass*, of its breed?

Comment: You should only use inheritance when a child is a special kind of its parent. For example, a Mango is a special kind of Fruit. So, Mango can be a subclass of Fruit

Comment: Well not necessarily. Because for example I'd like Breed to have a list of coat colors associated with that breed, and then Dog to have the actual coat colors for that individual dog.

Comment: You realise that's not an argument against my suggestion?

Comment: My apologies, I misinterpreted your answer. So you're suggesting I go with relations then?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, inheritance represents an 'is a' relationship and composition a 'has a' relationship. Is a dog a breed? Not really. Breed is a property or trait of a dog, a dog has a breed. Inheritance is not appropriate in this case.